# Creating two Columns on a Page.

Tags: columns

The page I am trying to edit is as follows:

http://www.blackaero.com/shop-2

I am using the Wordpress Simple PayPal Shopping Cart Plugin and I want the two items I have on the page in two columns to make it look more organized.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: For future reference this is a CSS styling question not specifically related to WordPress, hence the downvote.

Comment: Oh I apologize.

Comment: No problem really, pretty sure StackOverflow section is for CSS questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the CSS:

```
.wp_cart_product_display_box {float:left;}
```

You will probably want to add something like `margin-right: 30px;` to that.

PS. You have a rogue `</p>` tag on the page also, check your content/template for syntax errors.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but coding is not my strong suit. When I create the product box this is what I input:

[wp_cart_display_product name= "Eggfinder LCD Enclosure Belt Clip/Attachment  Point" price="99.00" thumbnail="http://www.blackaero.com/wp-content/gallery/gps-enclosure/20160318_180551.jpg" shipping="0.0001" description= "Additional Accessory for the LCD Receiver" var1="Color|White|Black|Yellow|Red|Blue"]

Where would I add your above CSS code?

Comment: sometimes your theme will have a space to add CSS, otherwise probably the easiest thing to do is add a custom css plugin from the wordpress repository there are many available.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been awake for 20 hours and just couldn't find an answer on Google. So Thank you!

Comment: lol, no problem - we've all been there!